# How to render header footer and main contain separate in nestjs

Tags: handlebars.js, nestjs

i try this it's working but I have multi pages and i wanna make the same header footer and render on each page ..

```
@Get('test')
@Render('B2B/test.hbs')
createClient() {
   return { message: 'Hello create_client!' };
}
```

Comment: any one can help???